# Linear Transformations - prove that $ST = 2TS$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

There is linear transformation $S,T : \mathbb{R}_n[X] \to\mathbb{R}_n[X]$ . $T: T( p(x))=p(2x)$. $S:S(p(x)) = p'(x)$?

Where $\mathbb{R}_n[X]$ denotes polynomials with power up to $n$.

prove that $ST = 2TS$.

how can one prove this equality and does it exist ? tried using standard polynomial equation of $1 +x+x^2$ did not work.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be a good idea to have your *question* be self-contained in the body of your question and your title be descriptive.  Placing half the question (only) in the title is poor practice.

Comment: Does your "$R$" mean "$\Bbb{R}$" (`$\Bbb{R}$`)?  What is "$R[x]n$"?  (Maybe you mean $(\Bbb{R}[x])^n$, the set of $n$-element vectors with elements from the polynomials on $x$ with real coefficients?  If so, do you really mean to take component-wise vector derivatives?)

Comment: sorry if it wasnt clear, but by R[x]n i meant polynomials with power up to n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have, for $p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k$,
$$
STp(x)=S\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_k(2x)^k\right)=S\left(\sum_{k=0}^n2^ka_kx^k\right)
=\sum_{k=1}^nk\,2^ka_kx^{k-1}.
$$
And
$$
TSp(x)=T\left(\sum_{k=1}ka_kx^{k-1}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^nka_k(2x)^{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^nk\,2^{k-1}a_kx^{k-1}.
$$
The two expressions differ by a factor of $2$, and $p$ was arbitrary. So 
$$
ST=2TS.
$$

Comment: This is more targetted at OP:  In what way is this $p(x)$ an element of "$R[x]n$"?

Comment: @EricTowers Target missed. :-(

Answer (score 1):

This is a really cute problem! When you think about it some more it becomes clear that the seemingly curious fact $ST=2TS$ is more or less obvious, and it should be possible to provide an abstract nonsense proof. Here it is:

Write $p=\bigl(x\mapsto p(x)\bigr)$. Then $Tp=\bigl(x\mapsto p(2x)\bigr)$, and the chain rule then gives $$STp=\bigl(x\mapsto p(2x)\bigr)'=\bigl(x\mapsto 2p'(2x)\bigr)\ .\tag{1}$$
On the other hand, $Sp=\bigl(x\mapsto p'(x)\bigr)$, so that
$$TSp=\bigl(x\mapsto Sp(2x)\bigr)=\bigl(x\mapsto p'(2x)\bigr)\ .\tag{2}$$
Since $(1)$ and $(2)$ hold for all differentiable $p$ ($p$ doesn't  have to be a polynomial) it follows that $ST=2TS$.